# Restrict function generic type parameters

Tags: scala, generics

Having following structure:

```
trait ParentType
trait ChildType extends ParentType

case class FooBar[+T <: ParentType](s: String, data: T)
object FooBar {
  def apply[T <: ChildType](i: Int, data: T): FooBar[T] = new FooBar(s"$i", data)
}
case class Foo(a: Int) extends ParentType
case class Bar(s: String) extends ChildType


def function1[T <: ParentType](obj: FooBar[T]): Unit = ()
def function2[T <: ChildType](obj: FooBar[T]): Unit = ()
```

Is possible(and in what way) to change the signature(with generics declaration) of `function1` and `function2` such that `function1` can only except parameters of `FooBar` with type `T` that is direct descendant of `ParentType`(and prohibit any `T` that is direct descendant of `ChildType`) and `function2` in another way around - except only parameters with `T` that are direct descendants of `ChildType` and prohibit all `ParentType` `T`'s

In other words this shouldn't compile

```
function1(FooBar("a", Bar("1"))) //because Bar is not direct descendant of ParentType
```

Comment: Why do you want such a complex and weird type of restriction? Your requirement is even a direct violation of the **Liskov** principle which makes me think this in an XY-Problem and that your correct solution using inheritance is a failed abstraction. - Maybe if you can explain your meta-problem we may provide a better alternative.

Comment: Let's say that ParentType is `Animal` and ChildType is `Mammal`. I want `function2` to accept "containers" FooBars of Mammals only, and `function1` - all other group types of animals(but not mammals): `Fish`, `Reptile` etc. Hope it's more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: You can do `def function1[T](data: FooBar[T])(implicit ev: T <:< ChildType)` for `function2` you may rather overload `function1` so that if the evidence is not found the overload is picked _(not sure if that would work)_ or pull out `=!:=` from **Shapeless**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks, using shapless solves my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of  @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  (see his comments to the question) I managed to achieve what I wanted. So, taking into account as well that I need context bound for `Arbitrary` from scalacheck to be in these functions declarations, Luis suggestion to use shapless(in particular I found out that `<:!<` can solve my problem) helped

```
    import shapless._

    def function1[T <: ParentType](obj: FooBar[T])(implicit: arb: Arbitrary[T], ev: T <:!< ChildType): Unit = ()
    def function2[T <: ChildType : Arbitrary](obj: FooBar[T]): Unit = ()
```

Unfortunately I didn't manage to achieve the override of `function1`(just with different `ev` types), but having those functions with different names I can reuse `function1` from `function2`(I need just to call `function1` with explicit parameter for `<:!<` instance which is `shapeless.nsub`).

So with this solution any `ChildType` instance can't be applied to `function1`(at least as is) because such application results in

```
ambiguous implicit values:
 both method nsubAmbig1 in package shapeless of type [A, B >: A]A <:!< B
 and method nsubAmbig2 in package shapeless of type [A, B >: A]A <:!< B
 match expected type Bar <:!< ChildType
```

I guess this is what was designed behind usage of `<:!<` type(but if explicitly to specify an instance of `<:!<` it will work)

Here is a [link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/K3UzbNJDQam7akUgj2HQNw) to scastie worksheet to try out the problem

Answer (score 1):

The question does not make very much sense, I am afraid, but to answer what you wrote in comments:

> I want function2 to accept "containers" FooBars of Mammals only

So, it should be `def function2(m: Foobar[Mammal])`

> and function1 - all other group types of animals(but not mammals)

This is a weird requirement. If you are sure you need this (I really, really doubt you actually do), I suggest something like this:

```
   trait NotMammal extends Animal
   class Fish extends NotMammal
   class Reptile extends NotMammal

   ... 

   def funcction1(n: Foobar[NotMammal]) = ???
```

Comment: so you're basically suggesting to make some marker type for "those who are not mammals"? Regarding functions, will it work if I also need that functions should have a context bound for `T` (let's say `Arbitrary` from scalacheck, and I want to use that functions with `scalacheck-shapless` for generating `arbitraries` for each particular type: `Monkey` of mammals, `Salmon` of fish etc)?

Comment: @maks Sorry, I have no idea what those things are ... or what you are trying to achieve.